# Why does reference exception does not come in case of undeclared object properties?

Tags: javascript

In JS, doing a read access on undeclared variable gives reference exception.

I tried following code:

```
var obj = { };
console.log(obj.v1);
```

This prints undefined

```
console.log(v2);
```

While this throws exception.

What is the reason for different behavior?
I was expecting exception in both cases as both v1 and v2 are undeclared.

EDIT: More confusing is the fact that if v2 was declared in global scope, it would have become property of window object. So does it not become similar to the case that I am accessing an undeclared property of window object? Same as case 1?

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { };

console.log(obj.v1);
```

`obj` is defined but it's property v1 doesn't exist, so output `undefined`.

---

```
console.log(v2);
```

`v2` is not declared so, output like `Uncaught ReferenceError: ...`

---

for `window.v2` output is `undefined` but for only `v2` output is:  `ReferenceError`.

```
var foo = 1;
// Explicit global/window variable (new variable)

bar = 2;
// Implicit global/window variable (property of default global object)
```

Comment: but if v2 was decalred in global scope, it would have become property of window object. So does not it become similar to the case that I am accessing undeclared property of window object? same as case 1?

Comment: Cause it's the default property of `global` or `window` object.

Comment: "it would have become property of window object" -> for `window.v2` output is `undefined` but for only `v2` is ReferenceError.